Trouble uploading files to nodejs app hosted on Netlify
So i have a nodeJS app using multer to upload excel file and read it , but there is no saved file . The app is woking fine on localhost , the trouble is somewhere in configuring Netlifly
Here is the project https://quiz-gvv.netlify.app
Here is Github https://github.com/GerganaVVladimirova/Quiz.git
There is another problem , after uploading the file I should be redirected to quiz.html , but it is not happening on Netlifly , only on localhost
The file which works with the app is default..xlsx in folder functions\uploads
here is my api.js
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const router = express.Router();

const fs = require("fs");
const xlsx = require("xlsx");
const { ok } = require("assert");
const unlinkAsync = promisify(fs.unlink);


// Serve static files from the "public" directory
app.use(express.static("../dist"));

let excelFilePath = '';
let exam = 0;
let questions = [];

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("file");

router.post('/upload',upload, async (req, res) => {
 
  exam = req.body.picker;
  excelFilePath = req.file.path; // Save the path of the uploaded file

  const workbook = xlsx.readFile(excelFilePath);

  let sheetNumber = Number(exam)-1;
  
  const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[sheetNumber]; 
  const sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];

  // Parse the sheet data into JSON format
  const excelData = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);

  if (excelData) {
      questions.push(objQuestion);
    }
  }

  await unlinkAsync(req.file.path);

  res.redirect('quiz.html');

});

router.get('/questions',(req,res)=>{
  // console.log(questions)
  if(questions){
    res.json({questions});
  }
});

app.use('/.netlify/functions/api', router);
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);

// app.listen(port, () => {
//   console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
// });

Here is the code from postman 
<body>
<pre>Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open &#39;uploads/1715433402132-default.xlsx&#39;</pre>
</body>

